# How to use C complex numbers in 'language=c++' mode?

Tags: cython

Most of my library is written with Cython in the "normal" C mode. Up to now I rarely needed any C++ functionality, but always assumed (and sometimes did!) I could just switch to C++-mode for one module if I wanted to.

So I have like 10+ modules in C-mode and 1 module in C++-mode.

The problem is now how Cython *seems* to handle complex numbers definitions. In C-mode it assumes I think C complex numbers, and in C++-mode it assumes I think C++ complex numbers. I've read they might be even the same by now, but in any case Cython complains that they are not:

```
openChargeState/utility/cheb.cpp:2895:35: error: cannot convert ‘__pyx_t_double_complex {aka std::complex<double>}’ to ‘__complex__ double’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double cabs(__complex__ double)’
 __pyx_t_5 = ((cabs(__pyx_v_num) == INFINITY) != 0);
```

In that case I'm trying to use cabs defined in a C-mode module, and calling it from the C++-mode module.

I know there are some obvious workarounds (right now I'm just not using C++-mode; I'd like to use vectors and instead use the slower Python lists for now).

Is there maybe a way to tell my C++-mode module to use C complex numbers, or tell it that they are the same? If there is I couldn't find a working way to ctypedef C complex numbers in my C++-mode module... Or are there any other solutions?

---

**EDIT:** Comments of DavidW and ead suggested some reasonable things. First the minimum working example.

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extra_compile_args=['-O3']
compdir = {'language_level' : '3'}

extensions = cythonize([
                        Extension("cmod", ["cmod.pyx"]),
                        Extension("cppmod", ["cppmod.pyx"], language='c++')
                       ], 
                       compiler_directives = compdir
                      )

setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = extensions
     )

import cppmod
```

cmod.pyx

```
cdef double complex c_complex_fun(double complex xx):
    return xx**2
```

cmod.pxd

```
cdef double complex c_complex_fun(double complex xx)

cdef extern from "complex.h":
    double cabs(double complex zz) nogil
```

cppmod.pyx

```
cimport cmod

cdef double complex cpp_complex_fun(double complex xx):
    return cmod.c_complex_fun(xx)*abs(xx)   # cmod.cabs(xx) doesn't work here

print(cpp_complex_fun(5.5))
```

Then just compile with python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace.

Now the interesting part is that (as written in the code) only "indirectly" imported c functions have a problem, in my case *cabs*. So the suggestion to just use *abs* actually does help, but I still don't understand the underlying logic. I hope I don't encounter this in another problem. I'm leaving the question up for now. Maybe somebody knows what's happening.

Comment: A [mcve] with two modules would make your question clearer.

Comment: `abs(num)` should be translated into the right thing from any language. It doesn't solve the general problem though

Comment: I extended my post to include your suggestions; DavidW and ead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the fact, that one module is compiled as a C-extension and the other as a C++-extension - one can easily reproduce the issue in a C++-extension alone:

```
%%cython -+ 
cdef extern from "complex.h": 
    double cabs(double complex zz) nogil

def cpp_complex_fun(double complex xx):
    return cabs(xx)
```

results in your error-message:

> error: cannot convert `__pyx_t_double_complex {aka
>   std::complex<double>}` to `__complex__ double` for argument `1` to
>   `double cabs(__complex__ double)`

The problem is that the complex numbers are ... well, complex. Cython's strategy (can be looked up [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/e6315294395ad44e667a804710938ee799575296/Cython/Utility/Complex.c#L4) and [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/e6315294395ad44e667a804710938ee799575296/Cython/Utility/Complex.c#L56)) to handle complex numbers is to use an available implementation from C/CPP and if none is found a hand-written fallback is used:

```
#if !defined(CYTHON_CCOMPLEX)
  #if defined(__cplusplus)
    #define CYTHON_CCOMPLEX 1
  #elif defined(_Complex_I)
    #define CYTHON_CCOMPLEX 1
  #else
    #define CYTHON_CCOMPLEX 0
  #endif
#endif
....
#if CYTHON_CCOMPLEX
  #ifdef __cplusplus
    typedef ::std::complex< double > __pyx_t_double_complex;
  #else
    typedef double _Complex __pyx_t_double_complex;
  #endif
#else
    typedef struct { double real, imag; } __pyx_t_double_complex;
#endif
```

In case of a C++-extension, Cython's `double complex` is translated to `std::complex<double>` and thus cannot be called with `cabs( double complex z )` because `std::complex<double>` isn't `double complex`.

So actually, it is your "fault": you lied to Cython and told him, that `cabs` has the signature `double cabs(std::complex<double> z)`, but it was not enough to fool  the c++-compiler.

That means, in c++-module `std::abs(std::complex<double>)` could be used, or just Cython's/Python's `abs`, which is [automatically translated](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/e6315294395ad44e667a804710938ee799575296/Cython/Utility/Complex.c#L130) to the right function (this is however not possible for all standard-function).

---

In case of the C-extension, because you have included `complex.h` as an so called "early include" with  `cdef extern from "complex.h"`, thus for the above defines `_Complex_I` becomes defined and Cython's complex becomes an alias for `double complex` and thus `cabs` can be used.

---

Probably the right thing for Cython would be to always use the fallback per default and that the user should be able to choose the desired implementation (`double complex` or `std::complex<double>`) explicitly.

Comment: I accepted your answer a while ago, because I don't disagree with what you're saying. I do understand that there are ways around my issues (as I have stated in my edits before your post as well), but I don't think how Cython handles c++/c modules in regards of complex numbers is ideal. But then again, I mixing 3 languages basically, so it's probably not that easy to find a better solution.

Comment: @oli Complex numbers in Cython are a can of worms. It gets even more complicated when coding on different platforms (i.e. Linux vs Windows) I have bugged the Cython-devs some time ago: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2513#issuecomment-407552578.